# What happens if an electrical current has two paths of unequal length?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrons, electric-current, voltage

Suppose I connect one 1 km cable and one 1000 km cable to the same pole of a power source and also connect them together at the other end. Suppose (theoretically) the longer cable has the exact same total resistance as the shorter one.

```
                  1 km
Pole A  -------------------------
         \                    /
          \      1000 km     /
           \------ ... -----/
```

In the sketch above, "Pole A" simply means a pole of the power source (either +/- of a DC source or a live pole of an AC source).
Also, `...` means that the cable is just routed in a long "detour" (not coiled up).

Are there any circumstances where this would be a problem?

- DC vs. AC power source?
- Open vs. closed circuit?
- etc.

I'm not a theoretical physicist, but technically it seems unlikely that it should be a problem, but somehow it seems unintuitive because of the delay (?) in the long cable compared to the short one... Just something that's been bugging me for a while (since staring at the third rail of a skytrain system going off several km's into the distance, while waiting for the train, in fact :)

Comment: Using just the theory of DC we can model the resistance by $R = \rho L /A$ where $A$ is the area of the traversal section of the cable and $L$ the length. See that it is proportional to the length so the current would tend to the $1km$ cable and a very little current would pass throughout the other cable.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What kind of problem do you think there might be?

Comment: @RafaelWagner As I said in the first paragraph, assume that theoretically the cables have identical total resistance.

Comment: @sammygerbil I don't know, that's why I'm asking the question. I'm thinking that there might be some weird stuff happening if it's connected to a AC source and the circuit is closed, since the current in the longer cable will be "delayed" and possibly out of phase with the shorter cable at the point where they meet... but I have no idea if that would happen or not.